# What is 'Dharan(Navel Displacement)' in Scientific terms?

Tags: medical-science, biology

In India ['Dharan'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navel_displacement) is supposed to be a kind of sprain which causes the Navel to get displaced. But as far as I know in modern science there is nothing like navel displacement.

What actually Dharan is, is that normally when we do some hard work in early morning without having eaten something there is some sprain which occurs in the stomach. Then the local physician checks the distance between left nipple and navel, and then compares it with the the distance between right nipple and navel. Then different people use different ways to make that distances same -- one I know is punching at the bottom of right or left foot.

> - Are there experimental or theoretical justifications for Dharan?
> - If Dharan is a misbelief then why is the distances b/w the navel and nipples come different?
> - In Dharan there is a pain like sprain in stomach. What is it called in modern science?

Comment: Who approved the edit to this question? It was closed nearly four years ago, and the edit adds absolutely no value - in fact, there are now *four* questions here instead of three. I'm reverting it.

Comment: Linked WP article claims "the distance between the navel center and the nipples, both distances should be identical, even a small difference of a millimeter is diagnosed as a displacement". Reproducibly locating the centre of nipples (let alone a navel) to the nearest mm is surely challenging, as is coping with chest movement from breathing and even abdominal distension from intestinal gas, etc - even if the basic premise that nipples & navel invariably form a perfect isoceles triangle is correct (in fact human bodies are generally not fully symmetrical).